# How to access images manipulations from Amazon s3 in iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-s3, image-manipulation, knox-amazon-s3-client

I am currently using Amazon S3 server, in that i am able to upload images from iPhone.
Is there a possibility to manipulate (cropping, transformations, effects, face detection) the images that i get from amazon server.

Comment: Yes. Yes there is. Normally by programming. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

There are no services in Amazon Web Services that provide image manipulation.

If you wish to manipulate images, you will need to write your own code (eg on a web server, using graphics libraries) or within your iPhone app.